# If file exist run mutiple commands, not just a single action

Tags: batch-file

What I want to do is a one time tsak in Windows 2008 that if a file exists( .txt) it runs an .exe and then deltes the file.

if exist c:\test.txt start c:\test.exe del c:\test.txt

Is it like the above statement?

Answer (score 1):

Combine commands with `&`:

```
if exist c:\test.txt start c:\test.exe & del c:\test.txt
```

or use parens:

```
if exist c:\test.txt (
    start c:\test.exe
    del c:\test.txt
)
```

Comment: `&&` is a conditional operator.  You combine commands with just one `&`